# Is it possible to get the arguments from a sub or function in vb2005 as an array?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is it possible to get the arguments from a sub or function in vb2005 as an array?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  When I hear questions like this, I worry that they are based on an already wrong approach...

Comment: the why is simple, im using multithreaded classes and i need to use a delegate if im not on the "topmost" thread, ex. my eventhandler runs normally runs in its thread, so i check in my event handler if im indeed running in the form's thread, then if not i create a delegate and rerun the eventhandler on the form's thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using reflection:

```
Dim params() As System.Reflection.ParameterInfo = myObject.GetType().GetMethod("myObjectMethodName").GetParameters()
```

Comment: appears to be half right, in my sub it shows up defined as "nothing",
let me rephrase, how do i get the values of my arguments as an array from within the sub or function

Answer (score 1):

did you solve this? I'm not too sure about what you mean, but from your comment on your OP, are you looking to synchronize threads to make calls thread-safe?

```
Private WithEvents theThread As New threadedClass
Private Delegate Sub threaded_method_delegate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal var1 As Integer, ByVal var2 As String)

Sub threaded_method(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal var1 As Integer, ByVal var2 As String) Handles theThread.threaded_method
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        ' invoke this method on the same thread as 'Me'
        Dim d As New threaded_method_delegate(AddressOf threaded_method)
        d.Invoke(sender, var1, var2)
    Else
        ' this method is now running on the same thread
        ' do stuff here
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in VS 2010, but not 2005. This is a feature being added via the DLR or Dynamic Language Runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the member signature, then you could encapsulate all of the parameters into a single class, much like how an `EventArgs` object (or subclass thereof) is passed between event handlers in the conventional .NET manner.

Then just pass all the values by passing a reference to the encapsulating class itself.